# webservice for Daylight Saving

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a web service that accepts a (date, Latitude Degrees, and Longitude Degrees) for a certain City,and returns if Daylight Saving is on for that city in the given date or not.

any help please?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm) is what i've found on dst webservice.

You could call it using http://www.earthtools.org/sun/< latitude>/< longitude>/< day>/< month>/< timezone>/< dst>

Good luck with this ;)!

Comment: thanks for reply , but I am not looking for getting the Sunrise and Sunset Times, what I am trying to get the DST for the cities :)